# Aws Lambda Allias stuck at Update In Progress stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge, aws-lambda-containers

This is my cft for my aplication sharing below and it is created successfully for first time ,while I am updating the cft (codechange) ,the LambdaAllias is stuck in Update In Progress stage .Could someone please guide me on this .

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: AWS Serverless Quarkus HTTP - Flight Info svc

   FlightInfoService:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
     Handler: not.used.in.provided.runtime
     Runtime: provided
     Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          'Fn::Sub': '${InfraStackName}-FlightInfoSvcLambdaExecutionRoleArn'    
     CodeUri: component1/function.zip
     MemorySize: 1024
     Timeout: 900
     AutoPublishAlias: live
     ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
       ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 1
     DeploymentPreference:
       Type: !Ref SetDeploymentPreferencetype
       Role: 
          Fn::ImportValue:
            'Fn::Sub': '${InfraStackName}-FlightInfoSvcLambdaCodeDeployRoleArn'
       TriggerConfigurations:
          - TriggerTargetArn: !Ref AlertTopic
            TriggerName: DeploymentAlerts
            TriggerEvents:
              - DeploymentStart
              - DeploymentSuccess
              - DeploymentFailure
              - DeploymentStop
              - DeploymentRollback
       Alarms:
          # A list of alarms that you want to monitor
          - !Ref FlightInfoSvcErrorMetricGreaterThanZeroAlarm
          - !Ref FlightInfoSvcLatestVersionErrorMetricGreaterThanZeroAlarm
       Hooks:
        # Validation Lambda functions that are run before & after traffic shifting
         PreTraffic: !Ref FlightInfoSvcPreTrafficHook
         PostTraffic: !Ref FlightInfoSvcPostTrafficHook    
     Environment:
          Variables:
             REFERENCE_DATA_SERVICE_BASE_PATH: !Ref RefDataSvcBasePath
             REFERENCE_DATA_SERVICE_API_GATEWAY_ID: !Ref RefDataSvcGatewayId
             LOG_LEVEL: INFO
             DISABLE_SIGNAL_HANDLERS: true
             AWS_SECRET_ENDPOINT: secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
             AWS_SECRET_REGION: us-east-1
             ADD_ON_UPDATE_FAILED_FLAG: true
             FLIGHT_ORIGIN_DATE_TTL: 60
     Tracing: Active
     VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroups
        SubnetIds:
          Fn::Split:
            - ","
            - !Ref Subnets
```

I removed the reference variables and parameter section ,only keeping the function name where I am getting issue .